# weird behavior when searching with b'\x5e', but with b'\x4e' is ok

Tags: python, regex, byte

```
import re

def main():
    with open('test', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(b'\x1e\x2e\x3e\x4e\x5e\x6e')
        f.write(b'\x1e\x2e\x3e\x4e\x5e\x6e')
    with open('test', 'rb') as f:
        s = f.read()
        for i in range((len(s)//8)+1):
            print(' '.join(['{:02x}'.format(j) for j in s[i*8:(i+1)*8]]))
        regex = re.compile(b'\x5e')  # weird
        for match_obj in regex.finditer(s):
            start = match_obj.start()
            end = match_obj.end()
            print(start, end)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

after I executed the code with pattern b'\x5e', I got

```
1e 2e 3e 4e 5e 6e 1e 2e
3e 4e 5e 6e
0 0
```

if i changed the pattern to b'\x4e' and run again, I would get

```
1e 2e 3e 4e 5e 6e 1e 2e
3e 4e 5e 6e
3 4
9 10
```

why do they work in different ways?

how do I fix it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0x5e is "^" in ASCII, which is a regex metacharacter. You will need to escape it if you want to use it in a pattern literally.

```
>>> re.escape(b'\x5e')
b'\\^'
```